# Auto Layout: portrait to landscape inconsistencies

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm going through that 'Auto Layout is more effort than its worth' stage. 
I'm getting better but some parts just won't click & its frustrating to say the least
Below are images to help show where i am with this, plus what it returned from the simulator:

[image]

The Center '...' text label is centered V&H. All 4 buttons have a trailing bottom space constraint to this label. each button has a trialing space constraint to each other. 
[image]

When i add leading & trailing space constraints to the outer edges of the UI editor (above) i get this result which appears as i wished (below)

[image]

Yet rotating 90 degrees causes the 4 buttons to squash up and be non-viewable (in some attempts the 4 have just over lapped each other).

[image]

I've tried all different combinations of constraints, yet i can never achieve the view i wish for in both orientations. This question will probably receive criticism, but to be honest this is the only direct way of getting an answer, or even just some help. I've found that the online tutorials & examples just state what tools i have to use and don't venture into 'slightly more than basic' positioning of UI elements

Comment: If you would like to have some introduction into generating constraints in code in place of storyboard I'm here for you to show you how to write it to achieve your goal. I find storyboard too cumbersome to create more complex Auto Layouts.

Comment: do you feel code constraints have a lot more control on the final result? i've used android's XML layout before now, and whilst that was good for the end result, i did have trouble making it resolution independent (bigger screens etc) 

i'd be more than happy if you new of any good starting places for code layout, constraints

Comment: The 'General Auto Layout Concepts' and 'Auto Layout In Code' sections of [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/) helped me. To create constraints, I do not use the [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) because it also has its restrictions. I usually write a category on NSLayoutConstraints and build some custom functions that use `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial picture, the reason the labels appear orange like that is because there is an ambiguity in your constraints: specifically that they do not have anything telling them where they should be sitting with respect to the x-axis. Vertically they are attached to the center, but horizontally they are only attached to each other, and since none of them are attached to the edge or anything else as an x-axis anchor, there is an ambiguity.

In your second picture you have fixed this problem by anchoring both sides of your chain to the edges of the view. However in portrait this squishes them because those outer anchors are trying to stay in place, and it's choosing to squish the width constraint on your labels instead.

Here's what you can do to solve this problem: Choose one of your labels (doesn't have to be all) and give it a constraint to the horizontal center of the container, which in this case is the superview.

This will inform the labels where they are to be positioned with respect to the x-axis, but also prevent them from being squished by the sides of the view in portrait.

[image: horizontal center]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the custom category I wrote for NSLayoutConstraints:

First, the `NSLayoutConstraint+ConstructorAdditions.h` file:

```
//  NSLayoutConstraint+ConstructorAdditions.h
//
// The methods in this category can be used to create NSLayoutConstraints programmatically
// without taking the NSLayoutConstraints constructors.
// Note: view1 and view2 must be in the same subview hierarchy. If not, adding NSLayoutConstraints using these methods won't have no effect.
//
// Example for the right order of method calls creating Constraints:
//
// UIView* mySubview = [UIView alloc] init];
// [self.contentView addSubview: mySubview];
// [self.contentView addConstraint: [self height: 10.0 forView: mySubview]];


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NSLayoutConstraint (ConstructorAdditions)



// returns constraints that align view to top, leading, bottom and trailing edges of the superview according to the assigned padding value.
// the constraints in the returned array are (from index 0 to 3) in this order:
// leading, top, trailing, bottom
+ (NSArray*) makeView: (UIView*) view
fillBoundsOfSuperview: (UIView*) superview
      verticalPadding: (CGFloat) vPadding
    horizontalPadding: (CGFloat) hPadding;


// align edges of two views
// if one view is the superview, put it at the second position in the array
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) alignEdge: (NSLayoutAttribute) edge
                          ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                         relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                          spacing: (CGFloat) spacing;



// vertical spcacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is above the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) verticalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing
                                ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                               flexible: (BOOL) flexible
                               inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax;


// horizontal spacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is left of the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) horizontalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing
                             betweenViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                                 flexible: (BOOL) flexible
                                 inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax;




// vertical spcacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is above the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) verticalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views;


// horizontal spacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is left of the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) horizontalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing betweenViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views;




// height constraints
+ (NSArray*) equalHeightOfViews: (NSArray*) views
                         toView: (UIView*) view
                       distance: (CGFloat) distance
                       relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                     multiplier: (CGFloat) multiplier;
// fix heights
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) height: (CGFloat) height forView: (UIView*) view;
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) maxHeight: (CGFloat) height
                          forView: (UIView*) view;
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) minHeight: (CGFloat) height
                          forView: (UIView*) view;

// width constraints
+ (NSArray*) equalWidthOfViews: (NSArray*) views
                        toView: (UIView*) view
                      distance: (CGFloat) distance
                      relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                    multiplier: (CGFloat) multiplier;
// fix widths
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) width: (CGFloat) width forView: (UIView*) view;
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) maxWidth: (CGFloat) width
                         forView: (UIView*) view;
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) minWidth: (CGFloat) width
                         forView: (UIView*) view;




// center vertically
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) centerView: (UIView*) view
             verticallyInContainer: (UIView*) container;



// center horizontally
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) centerView: (UIView*) view
            hoizontallyInContainer: (UIView*) container;



@end
```

and here the `NSLayoutConstraint+ConstructorAdditions.m` file:

```
#import "NSLayoutConstraint+ConstructorAdditions.h"

@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (ConstructorAdditions)






+ (NSArray*) makeView: (UIView*) view fillBoundsOfSuperview: (UIView*) superview verticalPadding: (CGFloat) vPadding horizontalPadding: (CGFloat) hPadding
{
    /* padding must be > 0 !*/
    hPadding = hPadding < 0 ? 0 : hPadding;
    vPadding = vPadding < 0 ? 0 : vPadding;
    NSLayoutConstraint* top = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeTop ofViews: @[view, superview] relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual spacing: vPadding];
    NSLayoutConstraint* leading = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeLeading ofViews: @[view, superview] relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual spacing: hPadding];
    NSLayoutConstraint* trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing ofViews: @[view, superview] relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual spacing: hPadding];
    NSLayoutConstraint* bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeBottom ofViews: @[view, superview] relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual spacing: vPadding];
    //NSLayoutConstraint* width = [NSLayoutConstraint equalWidthOfViews: @[view, superview] distance: -2*hPadding relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual multiplier: 1.0][0];
    //NSLayoutConstraint* height = [NSLayoutConstraint equalHeightOfViews: @[view, superview] distance: -2*vPadding relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual multiplier: 1.0][0];
    return @[leading, top, trailing, bottom];
}







// align edges of two views
// if one view is the superview, put it at the second position in the array
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) alignEdge: (NSLayoutAttribute) edge
                          ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                         relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                          spacing: (CGFloat) spacing {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        if (edge == NSLayoutAttributeBaseline || edge == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing || edge == NSLayoutAttributeBottom || edge == NSLayoutAttributeRight) {
            spacing = -spacing;
        }
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                                  attribute: edge
                                                  relatedBy: relation
                                                     toItem: [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                                  attribute: edge
                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                   constant: spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}


// vertical spcacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is above the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) verticalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing
                                ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                               flexible: (BOOL) flexible
                               inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;

    NSLayoutRelation relation = flexible ? (inMax ? NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual : NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual) : NSLayoutRelationEqual;

    if (views.count == 2) {
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                  relatedBy: relation
                                                     toItem: [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                   constant: -spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}


// horizontal spacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is left of the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) horizontalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing
                             betweenViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                                 flexible: (BOOL) flexible
                                 inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;
    NSLayoutRelation relation = flexible ? (inMax ? NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual : NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual) : NSLayoutRelationEqual;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                  relatedBy: relation
                                                     toItem: [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                   constant: -spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}






// vertical spcacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is above the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) verticalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing ofViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
{
    NSLayoutConstraint* verticalSpacing = nil;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        verticalSpacing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: [views objectAtIndex: 0] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: [views objectAtIndex: 1] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier: 1.0 constant: -spacing];
    }
    return verticalSpacing;
}



// horizontal spacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is left of the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) horizontalSpacing: (CGFloat) spacing
                             betweenViews: (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
{
    NSLayoutConstraint* horizontalSpacing = nil;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        horizontalSpacing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: [views objectAtIndex: 0] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: [views objectAtIndex: 1] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier: 1.0 constant: -spacing];
    }
    return horizontalSpacing;
}








+ (NSArray*) equalHeightOfViews: (NSArray*) views
                         toView: (UIView*) view
                       distance: (CGFloat) distance
                       relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                     multiplier: (CGFloat) multiplier {
    NSMutableArray* constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: views.count];

    for (UIView* aView in views) {
        [constraints addObject: [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem: aView
                                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy: relation
                                                                 toItem: view
                                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             multiplier: multiplier
                                                               constant: distance]];
    }
    return constraints;
}



+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) height: (CGFloat) height forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem: nil
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                             multiplier: 1.0
                                               constant: height];
    return constraint;
}


+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) maxHeight: (CGFloat) height
                          forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem: nil
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                                   constant: height];
    return constraint;

}


+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) minHeight: (CGFloat) height
                          forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem: nil
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                                   constant: height];
    return constraint;
}



+ (NSArray*) equalWidthOfViews: (NSArray*) views
                        toView: (UIView*) view
                      distance: (CGFloat) distance
                      relation: (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                    multiplier: (CGFloat) multiplier {
    NSMutableArray* constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: views.count];

    for (UIView* aView in views) {
        [constraints addObject: [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem: aView
                                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy: relation
                                                                 toItem: view
                                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier: multiplier
                                                               constant: distance]];
    }
    return constraints;
}



+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) width: (CGFloat) width forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem: nil
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                                   constant: width];
    return constraint;
}


+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) maxWidth: (CGFloat) width forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem: nil
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                                   constant: width];
    return constraint;
}


+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) minWidth: (CGFloat) width forView: (UIView*) view {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem: nil
                                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier: 1.0
                                                                   constant: width];
    return constraint;
}



// center vertically
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) centerView: (UIView*) view verticallyInContainer: (UIView*) container {
    NSLayoutConstraint* centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem: container
                                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              multiplier: 1.0
                                                                constant: 0];
    return centerY;
}



// center horizontally
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) centerView: (UIView*) view hoizontallyInContainer: (UIView*) container {
    NSLayoutConstraint* centerX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: view
                                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem: container
                                                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              multiplier: 1.0
                                                                constant: 0];


    return centerX;
}





@end
```

Comment: I've accepted the other answer as it directly answers the question, however i intend to continue reading into auto layout through code as i don't feel i can entrust storyboard entirely for my project. many thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Simon. You're welcome. Just wanted to share these category methods with the community (doesn't fit into a comment, right? ;-)) if you or somebody else might be interested in. I know my answer does not face your question directly so I'm however glad If I could give you a little hook on programmatically using Auto Layout.